# Filter Out Unwanted Characters from XML Form

Tags: regex, asp-classic

I have some unwanted characters in my form string that I need to filter out.

I need help with a regular expression to remove some unwanted characters. I really don't know the first thing about building new ones, I have looked at tutorials but I still cant really get my head around it.

The form string comes into my asp code looking like this:

```
<HOLDERS><ACCOUNTHOLDER Title="" Initials="" FirstName="" Surname="" Name="AN'A"N&D & TEST'S"I&X" CifKey="ANA"D.TESt83" CustomerType="2" PrimaryPan="545435454534"/></HOLDERS>
```

I need to remove the ',",& in the Name and the cifKey. I have tried to do this with a simple

```
replace(replace(replace(string,"""",&quot;"),"'",&apos;),"&","&amp;")
```

however I NEED to retain the double quotes, ie empty string at Title="", Name="" etc etc and doing the above just replaces "" with

```
&quot;&quot;
```

which is not what I need.

The output needs to be in this form:

```
<HOLDERS><ACCOUNTHOLDER Title="" Initials="" FirstName="" Surname="" Name="AN&apos;A&quot;N&amp;D &amp; TEST&apos;S&quot;I&amp;X" CifKey="ANA&quot;D.TESt83" CustomerType="2" PrimaryPan="545435454534"/></HOLDERS>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: is <HOLDERS><ACCOUNTHOLDER Title="" Initials="" FirstName="" Surname="" Name="AN'A"N&D & TEST'S"I&X" CifKey="ANA"D.TESt83" CustomerType="2" PrimaryPan="545435454534"/></HOLDERS>  rendering propely on your page  as this breaks string format ?

Comment: No it isn't, it comes across from a hidden form and I am pulling it in from a Request.Form. Unfortunatly I am dealing with really old legacy code in this application. When the code is attempting to build a XML DOM object it fails because it cant parse it correctly. This is why I am trying to fix it by filtering out the string so the XML can be parsed correctly to the DOM object

Comment: Did you try to replace double quotes with some placeholder first (say `{{DPLQTS}}`, and then, after replacing individual double quotes, revert the placeholder?

Comment: I tried that but I still need the doubles quotes around Name="AN'A"N&D & TEST'S"I&X" but keeping the double quote in the string within name..if that makes sense.. I tried doing this but I cant just do it for 1 double quote without doing it for everything.

Comment: Is CifKey always after name? Is CustomerType always after CifKey?